# Adding multiple data to cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, cookies

I'm trying to put multiple data into a cookie using a button.
The cookie will be used as a shopping cart and on the buttonclick will receive an idnumber of a product.
Everytime I click a second button, it doesn't add the idnumber of that button to the cookie.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Request.Cookies["MyTestCookie"].Values.Add("", "3");
    Response.Write(Request.Cookies["MyTestCookie"].Values.ToString());
}
```

**EDIT**
I'm sorry, I just reread and saw I explained wrong.
I want to add 1 string of data per button.(Button1 gives value 3, Button2 gives value 4 etc)
I've made multiple buttons like this one, but they overwrite eachother when adding into the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't doing it the correct way.

In order to add to a cookie, you need to do something like this. I've put two ways of doing it

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // method one
    Response.Cookies["MyTestCookie"].Value = myValue;
    // method two
    Response.Cookies["MyTestCookie"]['cookieKey'] = myValue;
}
```

For each item you would want to add a new key/value pair, rather than a key/values pair. So it would maybe look something like this

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // get item key and value from somewhere, maybe commandname/commandargument, 
    // it's your own preference
    Response.Cookies["MyTestCookie"]['item'] = itemId;
}
```

You can refer to this for instructions as well. 
[ASP.NET Cookies Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx)